# sp_updatestats doesn't seem to work for non-sysadmin logins

Tags: sql-server, permissions

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU16)

When trying to update statistics under a user which is a member of `db_owner` database role via

`EXEC sp_updatestats;`

SQL Server throws an error:

> Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_updatestats, Line 15 [Batch
>   Start Line 0] User does not have permission to perform this action.

Even though MS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-updatestats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states that "ownership of the database (dbo)" is enough seems that it is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood the phrase

> Requires membership in the sysadmin fixed server role, or **ownership** of
>   the database (dbo)

"ownership of the database" means that this login **owns** this database.

This is not the same as "is a member of `db_owner database role`"

`Owner` of a database is one single `login`, while there may be as many db_owners as you want.

And in fact if you execute

```
exec sp_helptext 'sp_updatestats';
```

in the first rows you'll find:

```
declare @dbsid varbinary(85)

select @dbsid = owner_sid
    from sys.databases
    where name = db_name()

-- Check the user sysadmin
if not is_srvrolemember('sysadmin') = 1 and suser_sid() <> @dbsid
begin
    raiserror(15247,-1,-1)
    return (1)
end
```

This controls if the executor is a member of `sysadmin` server role or he `owns` this database: `suser_sid() <> @dbsid` where `@dbsid` is `owner_sid` of current `database`.

To find out the owner of some database you should execute

```
select owner_sid
from sys.databases
where name = 'some_db';
```

And you also can find it using SSMS:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Occurs that this `sp_updatestats` behaviour is some kind of a bug.
One way to solve it is to use another sp and then grant the user `execute` permission (if not `db_owner`):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.updstatistics
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo'
AS
     EXEC sp_updatestats;
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.updstatistics TO [<user>];
GO
```